# Why is RAID not recommended for Hadoop HDFS setups?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Various websites (like Hortonworks) recommend to not configure RAID for HDFS setups mainly because of two reasons:

1. Speed limited to slower disk (JBOD performs better).
2. Reliability

It is recommended to use RAID on NameNode.

But what about implementing RAID on each DataNode storage disk?

Comment: Hadoop already keeps multiple replicas of the same file so if a HDD fails it can recover it. It can also read from multiple datanodes at once so - if you used RAID 1 - you’ll waste even more storage, why do you bother setting up HDFS in the first place? - when you use RAID 0 - the possibility that your storage would fail is n-times as high (n == number of discs) and not worth the risk. When you use RAID5 it will be much slower, more expensive, .. than normal JBOD

Comment: @peter I consider RAID 5 at first place to avoid replication of file blocks. With parity disks, it can recover from failures. Expensive -> may be true. but slower? If say machine has 4 disks attached and each individually treated as node in JBOD and say if I configure raid using all these disk on particular machine, wouldn't be much better to read file block parallely? (Here I am not saying apply RAID on all machines of HDFS but kind of HDFS -> JOBD -> RAID for connected disk on same machine).

Answer (score 30):

RAID is used for two purposes. Depending on the RAID configuration you can get:

1. Better performance: reading a file can be spread over multiple disks or different disks can be transparently used to read multiple files from the same file system.
2. Fault-tolerance: Data is replicated or stored using parity bits on multiple disks. If a disk fails, it can be recovered from another replica or recomputed using the parity bits.

HDFS has similar mechanisms built in software. HDFS splits files into chunks (so-called file blocks) which are replicated across multiple datanodes and stored on their local filesystems. Usually, datanodes have multiple disks which are individually mounted (JBOD). A datanode should distribute its file blocks across all its disks / local filesystems.

This ensures:

1. Fault-tolerance: If a disk or node goes down, other replicas are available on different data nodes and disks.
2. High sequential read/write performance: By splitting a file into multiple chunks and storing them on different nodes (and different disks), a file can be read in parallel by concurrently accessing multiple disks (on different nodes). Each disk can read data with its full bandwidth and its read operations do not interfere with other disks. If the cluster is well utilized all disks will be spinning at full speed delivering the maximum sequential read performance.

Since HDFS is taking care of fault-tolerance and "striped" reading, there is no need to use RAID underneath an HDFS. Using RAID will only be more expensive, offer less storage, and also be slower (depending on the concrete RAID config).

Since the namenode is a single-point-of-failure in HDFS, it requires a more reliable hardware setup. Therefore, the use of RAID is recommended on namenodes.

Comment: great answer @Fabian

Answer (score 0):

RAID0 on and enterprise server is a huge mistake. I sure would like to meet the person that designed this. This makes no common sense to an IT operations manager. If you configure any of your local server disk with a RAID0 you risk a long and painful RAID0 recovery. If a single disk in a RAID0 fails that RAID partition becomes destroyed and it doesn't magically recover when the disk is replaced. Someone has to logon to the server and delete the old RAID partition and create a new one. This creates a lot of overhead in times when man hours and work cycles are at an all time high. An IT operations manager is either going to delay doing this due to more priority workload or refuse to do it because they don't have enough cycles to take people resources away for more important work. Then its going to get pushed off to another team. Then the politics begin and wham then it gets pushed back to the server owner/customer. If you wanted to make a RAID1 or SAN drive available then you could avoid that entire scenario.

Comment: who said anything about raid 0?

Comment: The only RAID type which makes technical sense with HDFS is RAID0.
However, it only adds more operational burden, so not worth it anyway.